# Вложенные generics

Tags: java, generics

Доброго времени суток, решил полезть в generics глубже, чем `SomeClass<T>`, и наскочил на сложности.

допустим есть класс

```
public class SomeClassA<T>{

}
```

и класс

```
public class SomeClassB<X>{

  public void someMethod(Object, X){}

}
```

Как мне в `SomeClassB` задать generic, чтобы он имел на входе `<SomeClassA<T>>`
и работал, соответственно, с `T`

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы хотите принимать в `someMethod` аргумент типа `SomeClassA<T>`? Можете примеры предполагаемого кода привести? Пока не совсем ясно.

Comment: я не знаю, как правильно объяснить. Давайте действительно попробую кодом.
`someClassB scb = new SomeClassB<SomeClassA<Integer>>;
scb.someMethod(new Integer(10));`

Comment: появляется ощущение, что я занимаюсь чем-то бесполезным, ибо логика программы никак не изменится в случае `SomeClassA<T>` `SomeClassB<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы имели ввиду наследование:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SomeClassB<Integer> scb = new SomeClassB<>();
            scb.print(10);
        }
    }

    class SomeClassA<T> {
        public void print(T obj) {
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }
    }

    class SomeClassB<T> extends SomeClassA<T> {
        public void print(T obj) {
            super.print(obj);
        }
    }
}
```